# How can I shield the textview scroll event when i set a html use html.from?

Tags: android, html, textview, richtext

As the title says, I use the textview to show the HTML. If the textview's height is not enough, the textview will can scroll and consume the touch event. How can I shield the textview's scroll when I showed the HTML.

Comment: Are you saying you want it to scroll, or you don't want it to scroll?

Comment: @danBuonocore if the text's area exceed the textview's area,the textview will resume the touch event(I am not sure if or not).I put the textview in the vertical viewpager,but It can't scroll vertical in the textview's area.look just like click event!